# Batch file to run .exe and replace file - upon .exe close swap existing file back

Tags: windows, batch-file

I apolgise, I'm a little rusty as I haven't touched batch in over 4 years....

I'm trying to replace a sound in my steam folder when the programme is launched which I achieved successfully by using a delay of a second or two. However on launch steam CRC's to check for corrupt/missing files and as a result I loose my replaced sound. To counter this I made another batch file to re-replace the old file when the application is closed thus next startup steam is happy!

```
//replace our unwanted sound
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"
pause 
timeout /t 4
xcopy "C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\steam sounds\message.wav" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\friends\message.wav" /Y
```

--these are separate files.

```
 //re-add our unwanted sound once the process is closed
start "" /W "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe"

xcopy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\friends\message.wav" "C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\steam sounds\message.wav" /Y
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a copy of the Steam message.wav and save it to a folder, and before you launch Steam.exe have it copy the original version in (might save time on the CRC check).
Then after it launches steam have the script copy in your .wav file.

Also just a note, // in batch file isn't commenting anything out will just throw errors, use REM command before the text.

So your script could look like this:

```
@echo off
SET STEAMPATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"
SET STEAM_WAV = "C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\steam sounds\original\message.wav"
SET MY_WAV = "C:\Users\thoma\Desktop\steam sounds\message.wav"
ECHO Putting original file in (to speed up CRC check)...
xcopy %STEAM_WAV% %STEAMPATH%\friends\message.wav /y /c
ECHO Starting Steam...
start "" "%STEAMPATH%\Steam.exe"
ECHO Waiting for Steam.exe to start...
:waiting
For /F "tokens=1" %%i In ('Tasklist /NH /FI "IMAGENAME EQ steam.exe"') Do Set sb=%%i
If /i %sb%==steam.exe (goto copyfile) Else (goto waiting)
ECHO Copying custom wav in...
:copyfile
xcopy %MY_WAV% %STEAMPATH%\friends\message.wav /y /c
ECHO DONE.....
TIMOUT /T 5
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! I edited your batch to suit my purpose however not only did it not launch steam but as far as I can tell the sound didn't copy either. I changed the 'start "" %STEAMPATH%' to just that and included the Steam.exe in the 'SET STEAMPATH' which worked initially however now does not...

Comment: You probably have to run it as admin, so that might mean as admin it cant access your thoma folder. So you might need to move the sound files to a separate folder other than the users folder.

Comment: Also take the @echo off out and run it from a cmd.exe so you can watch what it is doing.

Comment: I had no issue doing it before with a simple xcopy, I don't see why this would change that. I'll try without the echo now.